# Replace a single element in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array with unique elements. Is there a way to replace a certain value in it with another value without using its index value?

Examples:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
if array.include? 4
#  "replace 4 with 'Z'"
end
array #=> [1,2,3,'Z']

hash = {"One" => [1,2,3,4]}
if hash["One"].include? 4
#  "replace 4 with 'Z'"
end
hash #=> {"One" => [1,2,3,'Z']}
```

Comment: What are you looking for here: `array = [1,4,4];
if array.include? 4 # replace 4 with 'Z'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I just need to replace the 4(s) with another element of my choice. [1,4,4] => [1,'Z','Z']

Comment: I thought only the first of such instances should be replaced since the title says "single element". But it turns out not.

Comment: @sawa None of my arrays will have repeating elements so it won't matter.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
p array.map { |x| x == 4 ? 'Z' : x }

# => [1, 2, 3, 'Z']
```

Comment: Why go through the entire array if the first element equals 4?

Comment: How do you know '4' is only in the array once?

Comment: From the question: _"I have an array with unique elements"_

Answer (score 20):

You can do it as:

```
array[array.index(4)] = "Z"
```

If the element is not necessarily in the array, then

```
if i = array.index(4)
  array[i] = "Z"
end
```

Comment: He said he didn't want to use the item's index value.

Comment: While I agree with you, I think your comment is a bit harsh.

Comment: @MarkThomas Maybe. But I suspect the post was accompanied with a downvote, which made it worse.

Comment: You don't have to suspect. Why do you think my down vote justifies your reaction? All it means is I won't bother to offer an explanation in the future.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-map)

```
array = array.map do |e|
  if e == 4
    'Z'
  else
    e
  end
end
```

to edit the array in place, rather than creating a new array, use [Array#map!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21)

If you have more than one thing you want to replace, you can use a hash to map old to new:

```
replacements = {
  4 => 'Z',
  5 => 'five',
}
array = array.map do |e|
  replacements.fetch(e, e)
end
```

This make uses of a feature of [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), where if the key is not found, the second argument is used as a default.

Comment: What if my array is in a hash like in the Update?

Comment: @Lasonic Then: `hash['key'].map! do |e| ... end`

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution that assumes there will be no duplicates and that the order doesn't matter:

```
hash = { 'One' => [1, 2, 3, 4] }

hash['One'].instance_eval { push 'Z' if delete 4 }
```

[`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) sets the value of `self` to the receiver (in this case, the array `[1,2,3,4]`) for the duration of the block passed to it.

Comment: What if it's not the last element in the array?

Comment: I'd not do it that way, but it is interesting. Perhaps we have a rogue downvoter in our midst.

Comment: @Lasonic, if order is important, I believe Wayne's solution is better. It will replace _all_ occurrences of `4` with `'Z'`, maintaining their original order, and without using any indexes.

Comment: To grant that the array will continue with no duplicates you can use `hash['One'].instance_eval { push('Z').uniq! if delete 4 } `. :)

Comment: thank you Matheus but I don't understand why instance_eval needs to be used here?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, I used `instance_eval` to set the value of `self` inside the block to `hash['One']`. This allowed me to call the `push` and `delete` methods on `hash['One']` using an implicit `self`, eliminating the need to write `hash['One']` repeatedly. The code is equivalent to `hash['One'].push 'Z' if hash['One'].delete 4`.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira chrs, but isn't using `instance_eval` on `hash['One']` monkey patching the `Array` class?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) does not modify the receiver or its class in any way. The `Array` class is not modified. All it does is set the value of `self` to the receiver, and this modification is local to the block passed to it.